# how to create staging environment in heroku and push app

Tags: git, repository, heroku, staging

I have a rails project deployed on heroku which has only a production environment.

I've created a staging environment by doing:
"heroku create appname --remote staging"

the slug size for on my exsiting application is 4.4MB
and the .git repository is 85MB.

when I do git push staging master, it tries to upload all 85MB to heroku instead of just 4.4MB (which actually contains the application files).

is this what should happen? am I creating the staging environment right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deploy to Heroku, you need to do a `git push`. That pushes all the stuff in your repository. That's just what happens.

Comment: I agree, the OP will probably just have to endure the one-time, whole-history upload to the new staging app’s repository. If there was a way to tell Heroku that the new app was related to the original app, then they could enable Git object sharing to let user upload only the changes since some previous snapshot of the “forked” app’s repository. It is probably more (back-end) trouble than it is worth to offer this feature though.

Comment: yea, thats what I ended up doing.  I had initially thought that the compiled slug size would be 85MB, but its only about 10MB.  Thx for your responses guys.

Comment: Additionally, there's a heroku-specific dot-file `.slugignore` that permits you to list the files in the Git repository which Heroku should skip when compiling the repository into a slug. This can help cut down on slug size if you have large documentation files, PSDs, etc. in your repository but you don't want them in your slug.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the first few chapters in this book. http://railstutorial.org/ In fact, if you haven't already then read the whole thing :-)